# Difference between real user and system user accounts

Tags: active-directory, directoryservices, user-accounts

When I get UserPrincipal/DirectoryEntry records for a machine or Active Directory domain, is there a way to differentiate system accounts from real users?

For example, jsmith is a real user, while ASPNET or IUSR_machine are not. But relying on hard-coded known names doesn't seem to be the best way to filter out system users, because, there can be other accounts, too. Is there a better way?

For example, maybe there is "can logon interactively" flag, or, detect by checking that password is set, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The sample accounts you list are, for all intents and purposes, functionally the same as a user account you create for a named person.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Win32 [LookupAccountName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and LookupAccountSid methods. The last parameter (called accountType) is filled with the type of account, when the function returns.

```
 [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, UnmanagedCode = true)]
 [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
 [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
 public static extern bool LookupAccountSid(
        [In] string systemName,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] sid,
        [Out] StringBuilder name,
        [In, Out] ref uint nameLength,
        [Out] StringBuilder referencedDomainName,
        [In, Out] ref uint referencedDomainNameLength,
        [Out] out AccountType accountType);

 [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, UnmanagedCode = true)]
 [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
 [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
 public static extern bool LookupAccountName(
        [In] string systemName,
        [In] string accountName,
        [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] sid,
        [In, Out] ref uint sidSize,
        [Out] StringBuilder referencedDomainName,
        [In, Out] ref uint referencedDomainNameLength,
        [Out] out AccountType accountType);


/// <summary>
/// Defines the various account types of a Windows accunt
/// </summary>
public enum AccountType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// No account type
    /// </summary>
    None = 0,
    /// <summary>
    /// The account is a user
    /// </summary>
    User,
    /// <summary>
    /// The account is a security group
    /// </summary>
    Group,
    /// <summary>
    /// The account defines a domain
    /// </summary>
    Domain,
    /// <summary>
    /// The account is an alias
    /// </summary>
    Alias,
    /// <summary>
    /// The account is a well-known group, such as BUILTIN\Administrators
    /// </summary>
    WellknownGroup,
    /// <summary>
    /// The account was deleted
    /// </summary>
    DeletedAccount,
    /// <summary>
    /// The account is invalid
    /// </summary>
    Invalid,
    /// <summary>
    /// The type of the account is unknown
    /// </summary>
    Unknown,
    /// <summary>
    /// The account is a computer account
    /// </summary>
    Computer,
    Label
}
```

Comment: Will the returned AccountType not be the same for real users and system users - i.e. AccountType.User will be returned for both?

Comment: It will return something like "Alias" for the built-in administrators group. But I guess you are right about the ASPNET user or the IUSR_machine... The interactive logon privilege *might* be a clue then..

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ["samaccountname" property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to eliminate accounts that are not for users or groups.